# Batch - display folder names as options

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a small batch file which reads a folder (path is set as a variable in the file). It should display the names of all sub-folders as choices for the user and when the user chooses one that folder name should be saved in a variable for later use. The idea is that I have alot of branches I'm working on and in all of them there is a little jar file I want to run with this batch. So the batch present me a list of all branches in the folder and when I pick on it will start the jar file located in that branch folder.

EXAMPLE:

```
C:\code
```

contains

```
C:\code\branch1
C:\code\branch2
C:\code\branch3
```

Then I want the batch to present the following menu to the user:

```
1. branch1
2. branch2
3. branch3
```

When the user has chosen the folder name (f.ex. branch2) is saved in a variable for later use.

I've tried alot of googling, but nothing helpful came up. Sofar I've managed to read the sub-folders' names, but I dont know where to go from here.. can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: One thing I might suggest is that Powershell would make this a much easier prospect.  If that's an option for you, I'd recommend it!

Comment: Well as long as it is possible to create a file similar to .bat that I can run, then I'm happy :)

I'll look into PS.. ty :)

Answer (score 3):

We first need delayed expansion

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

Then need a list of all subfolders (assuming `%dir%` being set to the directory you want subfolders of):

```
set Index=1
for /d %%D in (%dir%\*) do (
  set "Subfolders[!Index!]=%%D"
  set /a Index+=1
)
set /a UBound=Index-1
```

Then you can present a choice (I added a little input validation, but it's not enough):

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,%UBound%) do echo %%i. !Subfolders[%%i]!
:choiceloop
set /p Choice=Your choice: 
if "%Choice%"=="" goto chioceloop
if %Choice% LSS 1 goto choiceloop
if %Choice% GTR %UBound% goto choiceloop
```

Then you can set a variable with the subfolder the user chose:

```
set Subfolder=!Subfolders[%Choice%]!
```

Comment: Hi it looks like it could do exactly what I want, but I'm having a minor issue.. no matter what directory I set %dir% to it still gives me a list of all folder in C:\

Comment: Awesome answer! I've been looking for something like this for a LONG time. Thanks!

Comment: Minor fix to handle directories with blanks correctly: `set Subfolders[!Index!]="%%D"`

Comment: @Andreas: The current code handles spaces just fine. I'm a bit against premature quoting of things that *may* be used in arguments, mostly because you then spend time removing those quotes in circumstances where you don't need them. Of course, you should quote usage of the `%Subfolder%` variable where it's necessary.